# How to find next textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to find next text area in following HTML Use case?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hthaava8/

jQuery: Code:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function (e) {
    var txtArea = $(this).next().find('textarea').eq(0);
    alert(txtArea.attr('id'));
    $(txtArea).focus();
    $(txtArea).val("nicetried");
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-8">
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-2 ">
            <p class="boldText">2.1 </p>


        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
    <p class="boldText">focus to next textarea?</p>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
    <textarea class="" id="commenty" style="height: 89px; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-8">
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-2 ">
            <p class="boldText">2.2 </p>


        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
    <p class="boldText">focus to next textarea?</p>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
    <textarea class="" id="commenty1" style="height: 89px; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-8">
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-2 ">
            <p class="boldText">2.3 </p>


        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5">
    <p class="boldText">focus to next textarea?</p>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5">
    <textarea class="" id="commenty2" style="height: 89px; overflow-y: hidden;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$(this)                            // Current textarea
    .parent()                      // Get parent
    .nextAll('.pure-u-md-1-5')     // Get all instance of textarea next to current element
    .first()                       // Get first instance
    .find('textarea')              // Select textarea element inside that
    .focus().val("nicetried");     // Focus and set value
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hthaava8/1/)

---

Without using the class:

You can use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$(this)
    .parent()
    .nextAll('div:has(textarea)').first() // Select `div` having textarea and get first
    .find('textarea')
    .focus().val("nicetried");
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hthaava8/3/)

Comment: Thanks for that can we do it without using class pure-u-md?